# How do I change sort() function to longer code?

Tags: python, recursion, median

I am trying to make the code which finds medians

```
def find_median_five(L):
    L.sort()
    return L[len(L)//2]
def MoM(L, k): 
    if len(L) == 1: # no more recursion
        return L[0]
    i = 0
    A, B, M, medians = [], [], [], []
    while i+4 < len(L):
        medians.append(find_median_five(L[i: i+5]))
        i+=5
    if i < len(L) and i+4 >= len(L):
        medians.append(find_median_five(L[i:]))

    mom = MoM(medians, len(medians)//2)
    for v in L:
        if v < mom: A.append(v)
        elif v > mom: B.append(v)
        else: M.append(v)

    if len(A)>=k: return MoM(A,k)
    elif len(A)+len(M): return MoM(B,k-len(A)-len(M))
    else: return mom

n, k = (int(x)for x in input().split())
L = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
print(MoM(L, k))
```

this is my current code, and it works fine. But what I want to make is change 'def find_median_five(L)part. 
So I changed to this

```
def find_median_five(L):
    L_len=len(L)
    if(L==0): return None
    median=int(L_len/2)# 
    if (L_len%2==1): return L[median]
    else: return (L[median-1]+L[mendian])/2
```

it's not working at all and I know my changed code is messed up. But have no idea where to fix or change it. can you please help me?

Comment: What is your specific question? See [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: I want to know how should i change my def find_median_five(L):
    L_len=len(L)
    if(L==0): return None
    median=int(L_len/2)# 
    if (L_len%2==1): return L[median]
    else: return (L[median-1]+L[mendian])/2 to make same with     L.sort()
    return L[len(L)//2]

Comment: Why did you change it, when it works?

Comment: i am studying algorithm of sort. so i tried to understand how sort() function actually works.

Comment: [Timsort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort)

Comment: thx, i will take a look.